# Extension method for with primitive parameters

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, constraints

I have an extension method declared in this way:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEntity> AsEnumerable<TEntity>(this IDBQueryable<TEntity> dbQueryable) where TEntity : class
{
    return dbQueryable.Query.AsEnumerable();
}
```

A sample of use would be the next one:

```
//It works properly
IDBQueryable<Customer> customers = GetCustomerSet();
customers.AsEnumerable();

// It cannot be compiled because int type doesn't fullfill
// the constrains of the extension method
// It must be a reference type in order to be passed as a parammeter.
IDBQueryable<int> customerIDs = GetCustomerIDs();
customers.AsEnumerable();
```

How can I have an extension method that works for the two use cases I have shown?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Eric `Int32` is ***identical*** to `int` in .NET; no boxing (it is merely a language-level alias; `int` === `global::System.Int32`)

Comment: Do you get a compilation error if you remove the constraint on your extension method?

Comment: @Eric The point is my POCOs Id is defined with an Id and this is not something which I'm allowed to change.

Comment: @Nick Yes I receive this error The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method '<TEntity>'

Comment: You're missing the important bit in your last comment: ...in the generic type or method '[important bit]<TEntity>'

Comment: @jersiovic where is that error coming from? does `IDBQueryable<T>` have this constraint? Or is that coming from ....? (fill in blank here)

Comment: @Marc you are right I forgot that IDBQueryable<T> has a class contraint. Many thanks. My first question on StackOverflow and I'm very impressed with your quick answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `where TEntity : class` constraint. There is no obvious need for a constraint here, and any use of `: class` or `: struct` will prevent one of the two use-cases.

Comment: I obtain a compilation error doing what you say. The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method '<TEntity>'

Comment: @jersiovic then you need to tell us where else has this constraint, because where-ever it is, it isn't in the question.

Comment: You are right I forgot that IDBQueryable<T> has a class constraint. Many thanks. My first question on StackOverflow and I'm very impressed with your quick answer

Comment: @jersiovic unless you remove that constraint, `IDBQueryable<int>` is impossible, then